# Columns name dropped on append in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

WinPython: pandas 0.16.1, py3.4

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                    'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                    'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                   index=[0, 1, 2, 3])
df1.columns.names=["hello"]
df1
hello   A   B   C   D
0      A0  B0  C0  D0
1      A1  B1  C1  D1
2      A2  B2  C2  D2
3      A3  B3  C3  D3
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['B2', 'B3', 'B6', 'B7'],
                    'D': ['D2', 'D3', 'D6', 'D7'],
                    'F': ['F2', 'F3', 'F6', 'F7']},
                   index=[2, 3, 6, 7])
df4.columns.names=["hello"]
df4
hello   B   D   F
2      B2  D2  F2
3      B3  D3  F3
6      B6  D6  F6
7      B7  D7  F7
```

I need to join dataframes like the ones shown above, but columns name `hello` (it is not a column as it may seem!) is dropped on append operation. Why? I have to force it like this: `pv.columns.names = df4.columns.names`

```
df1.append(df4)
     A   B    C   D    F
0   A0  B0   C0  D0  NaN
1   A1  B1   C1  D1  NaN
2   A2  B2   C2  D2  NaN
3   A3  B3   C3  D3  NaN
2  NaN  B2  NaN  D2   F2
3  NaN  B3  NaN  D3   F3
6  NaN  B6  NaN  D6   F6
7  NaN  B7  NaN  D7   F7
```

UPD: `concat`/`append` drops axis 0/1 names when they differ. So, i think, forcing `.names` after `append` is the best solution now.

Comment: Could you please accept my answer if my approach helps you solve the problem? Many thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

The [`DataFrame.append` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) is not as good as the [`pandas.concat` function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) for this purpose.

Using the [`pandas.concat` function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html), you will keep the index.

```
pd.concat([df1,df2])
        A       B   C       D   F
hello                   
0       A0      B0  C0      D0  NaN
1       A1      B1  C1      D1  NaN
2       A2      B2  C2      D2  NaN
3       A3      B3  C3      D3  NaN
2       NaN     B2  NaN     D2  F2
3       NaN     B3  NaN     D3  F3
6       NaN     B6  NaN     D6  F6
7       NaN     B7  NaN     D7  F7
```

Comment: `hello` is name of columns level [A,B,C,D,F]! I updated question to be clearer.

Comment: Ok, this was not very obvious from your pasted examples. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think `pd.DataFrame.combine_first()` would help.

```
df1.combine_first(df4)
Out[98]: 
hello    A   B    C   D    F
0       A0  B0   C0  D0  NaN
1       A1  B1   C1  D1  NaN
2       A2  B2   C2  D2   F2
3       A3  B3   C3  D3   F3
6      NaN  B6  NaN  D6   F6
7      NaN  B7  NaN  D7   F7
```

It is similar to `df1.update(df4)` but using a 'outer' join manner for unseen records in `df1`.

Answer (score -1):

I get this (Anaconda (Windows 64 bit), Python 3.4 , Pandas 0.16.1):

```
df1.append(df4)
Out[190]: 
     A   B    C   D    F  hello
0   A0  B0   C0  D0  NaN      0
1   A1  B1   C1  D1  NaN      1
2   A2  B2   C2  D2  NaN      2
3   A3  B3   C3  D3  NaN      3
0  NaN  B2  NaN  D2   F2      2
1  NaN  B3  NaN  D3   F3      3
2  NaN  B6  NaN  D6   F6      6
3  NaN  B7  NaN  D7   F7      7
```

Comment: no-no, `hello` is not a column: `df1.columns.names=["hello"]`. (Sample dataframes are from http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html )

Comment: oh, why do you want your columns to have a name like this? i've never seen this feature used before, maybe you can achieve what you want some other way?

Comment: when we do `dataframe.T` columns become index and cause i swap them several times and massively use MultiIndex, i need to preserve index levels names

Comment: hmm interesting use case, you might have to keep doing it manually though, what would be the desired functionality if the column series names were different?

Comment: i think names should be preserved on append if they are the same, otherwise dropped silently

Comment: fair enough, maybe raise it as a feature request in pandas issue tracker? https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues